# Car Hiccups when engine is cold 2002 Mustang

Tags: ford, mustang

I have a 2002 Mustang V6 that when I first drive it in a day the car hiccups a couple times. It only happens when the engine is cold. I can't figure out what is causing it. So far I put in a catalytic converter and fuel injection cleaner. 
Here are the error codes I'm getting. Any ideas?

P1000 On Board Diagnostics II Monitor / Driver Cycle Test Not Complete

P1401 DPFE Sens Circuit High Volt NON_MIL

P1450 Fuel Tank Vaccum Can Not Bleed NON_MIL

Answer (score 2):

Three separate areas which the codes are pointing to. Let's run them down one by one ...

> P1000 On Board Diagnostics II (OBDII) Monitor/Driver Cycle Test Not Complete

Causes are -

- The battery or PCM has been disconnected (Ford,Mazda)
- The diagnostic trouble codes have been cleared (Ford,Mazda)
- An OBD monitor concern occured before completion of the drive cycle (Ford)

This error occurred because the OBDII system had not totally reinitialized before another code occurred. While I haven't dealt with this before, this is not an issue to worry about at this time. If it continues, then it would be a worry, but it appears to be a generic error which occurs right after a reset has happened, then another code appears, which you have.

> [P1401](http://engine-codes.com/p1401_ford.html) DPFE Sens Circuit High Volt NON_MIL

The DPFE is the Differential Pressure Feedback Electronic sensor. It is part of the Exhaust Gas Recirculation (EGR) system on Ford Vehicles. This part seems to be an ongoing problem with many Ford vehicles around the same year as yours. Luckily it seems to be a fairly easy part to change out ... [this guy did it on his Ford Focus](http://engine-codes.com/p1401_ford.html) without any hand tools. You can read a [Technical Service Bulletin about it here](http://engine-codes.com/uploads/ford/04-11-1.pdf). This seems likely to be an issue which most people can fix by themselves without too much of an issue (knowledge is power!).

> [P1450](http://engine-codes.com/p1450_ford.html) Fuel Tank Vacuum Can Not Bleed

The possible causes as they have them listed are:

- Blocked EVAP canister or vent solenoid
- Kinked or collasped hose between canister and fuel tank
- Faulty Fuel Tank Pressure (FTP) sensor
- Fuel filler cap stuck closed, preventing vacuum relief

This problem may be a little harder to get worked out. You can do your best to check the above items, but it may require mechanic intervention.

I would get the DPFE fixed first and see if this doesn't eliminate the other two issues (well, at least for the codes popping again). I wouldn't worry at all about the P1000 code. The P1450 may be more problematic.

Comment: The P1450 error I've had for a couple years and where there wasn't an issue before.

Comment: Just by the nature of what it is, I would bet that it might not be an issue, per se, but something which you might want to track down one of these days then. I really think replacing the DPFE will fix your issue.